# Get e4 service without injection

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I'm trying to adapt an Eclipse RCP 3.x application to use some facilities from e4.  For this reason, there is no e4xmi file.

In particular, I need to get access to some services:

```
public class RunModeService {

@Inject
private static ECommandService commandService;
@Inject 
private static EHandlerService handlerService;

...
}
```

It would appear that if I instantiate the class myself (as I am doing) then none of the injection takes place.

Is it possible to get hold of these services another way?  If so, I can begin to hook into e4 and DI, by creating a command whose handler is instantiated by the framework and in which injection occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `IEclipseContext` you can get objects using:

```java
ECommandService commandService = eclipseContext.get(ECommandService.class);
```

`IEclipseContext` can be injected.

You can create your own objects using `ContextInjectionFactory` which will do DI on the object for your:

```java
MyClasss myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyClass.class, eclipseContext);
```

or you can do injection on an existing class instance with:

```java
ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myClass, eclipseContext);
```

In a view or editor you can get the Eclipse Context from the view / editor site using:

```java
eclipseContext = ((PartSite)getSite()).getContext();
```

**But** `PartSite` is an internal class so it really should not be used.

Comment: It seems that IEclipseContext needs to be injected as well.  From this question, I got hold of the BundleContext and used that to get an IEclipseContext: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316970/how-to-get-the-ieclipsecontext-in-an-activator.  However, my new context does not include an ECommandService, or indeed an MApplication.  I wonder if the application model is not created if you've created an e3 app.

Comment: That context is the specialized OSGi service context and only contains OSGi services. You need the context from MApplication or an MPart. All Eclipse 4 applications are e4 under the hood, 3.x apps just have a lot of compatibility code on top of e4.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually inject your class with the active `IEclipseContext`:

```
IEclipseContext context = getActiveEclipseContext();
RunModeService service = ContextInjectionFactory.make(RunModeService.class, context);
```

To get the active `IEclipseContext` without DI, you can use the example code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230722/3270595).